# Rename Serial.print() to shorter name (nickname)

Tags: printing

I need to create a nickname for Serial.print() to save space and make the code more readable (I've got dozens of print spaces and limited memory).

I've done it in the past, can't remember how, can't find my own code.

It looks something like: **#define Serial.print S.prt**

I'm using the most current Arduino IDE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#define S_prt Serial.print – Juraj
This answer was supplied by Juraj. It redefines Serial.print() to a shorter name (nick name).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).